# Deployment with Rake Causing Image Permission Errors (600)

Tags: ruby, rake, web-deployment, file-permissions

I'm deploying my website to my server with Rake for the first time and I've run into a slight issue.

**RAKEFILE**

```
desc 'Deploying the website...'
task :deploy do
  puts 'Deploying to server.com'
  user = 'user'
  server = 'server.com'
  path = 'server.com/html'
  sh "rsync -rtzh --delete _site/ #{user}@#{server}:#{path}"
  puts 'Fin!'
end
```

When I run `rake deploy` and enter the password, everything successfully uploads to the server; except some of the images aren't loading on the page. I had a look, and the files are definitely on the server, but I think the problem lies with the permissions of these images:

[image]

When I upload over FTP the files are set to 755 and they're visible on the site. When I do it with Rake, they're set to 600 and hidden.

Is it possible to set them to 755 or 644 or any idea why this is happening?

I could change the permissions for each and every image, but isn't the most elegant solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rake isn't really your problem here. Rake doesn't know anything about uploading files or setting permissions; it just runs the commands as defined in the task.

The actual file upload is happening via `rsync`. According to [the rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), you should be able to use the option `-p` (AKA `--perms`) to set the files copied to the destination server to have the same permissions as the source files.